# django login to previous page

Tags: python, django

From my django application I send an email which contains a link to an other page : domain/project/user/1, which requires the user to log in, so he is automatically redirected to domain/accounts/login. 
But when the user  does so , he is redirected  to: domain/project/ but I want him to be redirected to : domain/project/user/1.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the redirection is driven by `?next=` in the URL, provided you have the correct request context preprocessors in the settings.

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

And in the template, where you would be sending the user from,:

base.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Log me in here</a>
```

Comment: I saw that on another topic, but redirection is automatic, and I don't want to use link.

Comment: Then , you can write a middleware, which detects if `next` is present in context, and the link is originating from login, and automatically log the users in there.

Comment: I found the solution. In my application I use a middleware to log in, with this I can get the first URL : domain/project/user/1.
so I can edit the attribute ?next=  
`class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    ....
    def process_request(self, request):
    ....
    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL+'?next='+firstPath)`
Thanks